# How-To call a module when a user clicks a node title or read more link if($page)

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I would like to call a module from node.tpl.php like so (based on node id):

//This is my node--job_post.tpl.php

```
   <pre>

   <?php
         if ($page):
    $nid = $node->nid;
  switch($nid){
  case 4:  CALL A MODULE FOR NODE ID 4
  case 5:  CALL A MODULE FOR NODE ID 5
  break;
 }
  endif;
  ?>
 </pre>
```

If there is a better way to accomplish this , please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it works in Drupal.

You need to use [Hook_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x) **in a custom module `.module` file, NOT in the template.tpl.php file**. Which executes the code inside it whenever a node is viewed.

Ex:

**hello_world.module**

```
hello_world_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){ 

  //code to run when node is viewed goes here.

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. It works as expected.